# Choose Opening Location of PyQt4 QWidget window

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, qwidget

My main application has a button that pops up a new smaller window in front of my application, and I want to change the location of where the new window opens.

Currently the code to show the window is simply:

```
self.my_window.show()
```

where my_window is an instance of my QWidget Class.

How do I choose the coordinates of where the window opens in Windows OS?

Comment: try with {your widget}.move({x}, {y})

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `move()`:

```
 {your widget}.move({x}, {y})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.my_window.move(x_coord, y_coord)
```

where `x_coord` and `y_coord` are ints